# Chrome browser saving form inputs- what names/IDs used and why only some saved?

Tags: html, browser, cross-browser

I have a page on my site with two forms, one for log in and one for registering.

```
LOG IN-
<form name="login" id="login" method="post" action="php/login.php">     
    Email:   <input id="email"    name="email"    type="text">
    Password:<input id="password" name="password" type="password">
</form>

REGISTER-
<form id="register" name="register" method="post" action="php/register.php">
    Email:           <input id="r_email"            name="r_email"            type="text">
    Confirm Email:   <input id="r_email_confirm"    name="r_email_confirm"    type="text">
    Password:        <input id="r_password"         name="r_password"         type="password">
    Confirm Password:<input id="r_password_confirm" name="r_password_confirm" type="password">
</form>
```

When I've tested it, Chrome is saving the log in form's email and password (id email and password) and the register form's confirm email and password (id r_email_confirm and r_password).

Any ideas why it is saving these values?

Comment: Aside: Use `type="email"` for email fields.

Comment: Just been reading up on it, will change it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's been an issue in Chrome:
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/f6zhGC8lVw4

It's been recommended to use

```
<form autocomplete="off"...
```

for the time being, which is a bit annoying.